# How to select the last inserted row in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with two columns and a table model that uses a class which works with a hash map. The elements of this map are the table rows.

Every time I add a new element I need the element to be selected, regardless of any sorting. Now, I've tried using the following method:

```
int lastRow = table.convertRowIndexToView(tableModel.getRowCount() - 1);
table.setRowSelectionInterval(lastRow, lastRow);
```

The problem is, this works only when I'm adding data in a sorted fashion (e.g. "A", "B", "C" and not even then since "D", for example, is placed ahead of A once added). Could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: How about create a class that extends JTable that stores the last element inserted, or keeps a list of the insert order?

Comment: Robin is correct, don't use a HashMap, prefer an ArrayList as a data source

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely in your `TableModel`, since the code you posted is just fine. You mention you use a `HashMap` for storing the data of your `TableModel`. Problem with a `HashMap` is that it hasn't any ordering. Adding an element to it might alter the order in which you get the elements in the map.

Better to use a data structure which respects the ordering.

Comment: Yeah, I realized the HashMap was the problem. I fixed the issue by going through my table after adding a new element, comparing the key as I go along and breaking at the spot the key equals a key from the table. That was the row I needed selected and then I simply called the lines above.

Comment: @NikolaLuburic sounds like your model implemenation could be invalid: the sequence of rows shouldn't be changed by an insert. If an insert indeed does change the sequence of existing row, the model must fire a dataChanged (which will loose any selection and pose the problems you have :-).

Answer (score 2):

better could be to use [prepareRendered for hightlighting max row index from XxxTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909039/714968)

[`JTable` could be `Sorted and Filtered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) too, then last added row couldn't be visible in `JTables` view

depends of [ListSelectionMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), but by default you can do

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(lastRow, lastRow);
table.setColumnSelectionInterval(columnMinIndex, columnMaxIndex);
```

for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame`, `JTable in JScrollPane` and a new `addRow` fired from `swing.Timer`