# How to add and delete table in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, addition

I have a code for making table and sort the data that input there. What if I want to add some action using button to add the row than fill the data and can delete the row too.
Here is my code:

```
public class TableSortDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Nama",
                                        "NIM",
                                        "IPK"};
        private Object[][] data = {
        {"", new Integer(0),new Double(0)}
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;

        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use HashMap?

Comment: HashMap caused some issues with sorting, inserting row at index, etc

Comment: Sorting shouldn't effect the physical model and should be done virtually

Comment: @MadProgrammer aaaaach I'm really don't want to win, but I can't resist, one of [describtions here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14156223/714968) by (@Robin), another are you can to searching (if I remember correctly) in posts by (@JB Nizet)

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, I see your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For JTable based on AbstractTableModel is required to override

   - [public void addRow(Object[] rowData)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) with proper notifiers (then after is new row displayed in JTables view) [fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29),
   - [public void removeRow(int row)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow%28int%29) with proper notifiers (then after is deleted row removed from JTables view) [fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29)
2. I'd be use DefaultTableModel ([see my post, how easy everything could be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664124/714968)), strongly recomend for newbee
3. everything is described in [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), rest is (correctly) in concrete APIs

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why don't you use an **ArrayList** to represent your entities being displayed in the rows. Instead of :

```
private Object[][] data = {
{"", new Integer(0),new Double(0)}
};
```

Have something like :

```
private ArrayList<Thing> myThings;
```

It makes things soooo much simpler.

If you want to add or remove rows, then just add two methods to the table model such as :

```
public void addThing(Thing t) {..}
public void removeThing(Thing t) {..}
```

And follow it up with a **fireTableDateChanged()**;

Comment: From a performance point of view, it would be better to use fireTableRowsInserted/deleted