# How to set Icon to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe

I tried this way, but it didnt changed?

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Desktop\\favicon(1).ico");
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

Comment: There seems to be some problem in your file path. Default image icon will be set if not image found in the path specified.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Better use a .png file; .ico is Windows specific. And better to not use a file, but a class resource (can be packed in the jar of the application).

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("/some/package/favicon.png");
// iconURL is null when not found
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

Though you might even think of using setIconImages for the icon in several sizes.

Comment: i am recieving null pointer exception all time even though Image path is correct

Comment: A late response: the icon should be in the same jar as the class on which you call getClass(), and the path is case-sensitive using `/`.

Comment: Do you know how to get the favicon from a weburl and to show at setIconImage

Comment: @Spritzig The favicon is by default under `/favicon.ico`. It can be specified in the HTML head, something like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">`. Do a search. Hopefully it actually is a .png, not an .ico.

Comment: Thanks but I am working with android studio, can you check my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233815/how-to-use-bitmap-to-show-a-favicon-of-an-web-for-a-viewholder

Comment: @Spritzig removing the query string "?..." and adding "/favicon.ico" might often do, if it were not for the Windows .ico format. Sometimes it is a .png in disguise. Often one has to parse the HTML if the site specifies favicon.png or such. That is some work to do. Consider a built-in list of frequent used sites.

Comment: Can you provide an answer or code for my question ?

Comment: @Spritzig sorry, a .ico can be downloaded manually, from /favicon.ico or inspecting the HTML for a link to an other path. If it is .ico I don't think java can turn it into an ImageIcon. I would have answered your linked question if I could, but this requires from you some investigation into both problems: .ico and link.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you for your time, I appreciate that.

Comment: Yes my issue was that I was using a `ico` file. Switched to PNG and it worked!

Comment: @JFreeman one point: a .ico can contain several images in different resolutions. The [setIconImages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages-java.util.List-) can be used for several (single-file) images too; for the larger alt-tab icon etc. I did not mention earlier to not further confuse the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Try putting your images in a separate folder outside of your src folder. Then, use ImageIO to load your images. It should look like this:

```
frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("res/icon.png")));
```

Comment: The answer above did not work for me but this works!

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found the main issue in setting the jframe icon. Here is my code. It is similar to other codes but here are few things to mind the game.

```
    this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Icon.png")).getImage());
```

1) Put this code in jframe WindowOpened event

2) Put Image in main folder where all of your form and java files are created e.g.

```
src\ myproject\ myFrame.form
src\ myproject\ myFrame.java
src\ myproject\ OtherFrame.form
src\ myproject\ OtherFrame.java
src\ myproject\ Icon.png
```

3) And most important that name of file is case sensitive that is icon.png won't work but Icon.png.

this way your icon will be there even after finally building your project.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
    frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(".\\res\\icon.png"));
```

For the export jar file, you need to configure the build path to include the res folder and use the following codes.

```
    URL url = Main.class.getResource("/icon.png");
    frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yon can try following way,

```
myFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Icon.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to set the Icon of a `JFrame`

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

  try{ 
    setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("res/images/icons/appIcon_Black.png")));
  } 
  catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy these few lines of code in your code and replace "imgURL" with Image(you want to set as `jframe` icon) location.

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

//Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("A window");

//Set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file.
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following utility class to set the icon for [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instances:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WindowUtilities
{
    public static void setIconImage(Window window)
    {
        window.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(WindowUtilities.class.getResource("/Icon.jpg")));
    }

    public static String resourceToString(String filePath) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = WindowUtilities.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        return toString(inputStream);
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/3764804
    private static String toString(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A"))
        {
            return scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
        }
    }
}
```

So using this becomes as simple as calling

```
WindowUtilities.setIconImage(this);
```

somewhere inside your class extending a `JFrame`.

The `Icon.jpg` has to be located in `myproject\src\main\resources` when using `Maven` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Maven` and have the structure of the project, which was created by entering the command:

```sh
mvn archetype:generate
```

The required file `icon.png` must be put in the `src/main/resources` folder of your maven project.

Then you can use the next lines inside your project:

```java
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./icon.png"));
setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

Answer (score 0):

My project code is as below:

```
private void setIcon() {
       setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/slip/images/cage_settings.png")));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResource("konashop/com/icon.png"))); // the URL should be within the src with the classes
frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

Comment: Try not to post answers that contain code only. Look at the other answers to this question. They contain both code and explanations.

Answer (score -1):

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(URL).getImage());
```

/*
frame is JFrame
setIcon method, set a new icon at your frame
new ImageIcon make a new instance of class (so you can get a new icon from the url that you give)
at last getImage returns the icon you need
 it is a "fast" way to make an icon, for me it is helpful because it is one line of code
*/

Comment: please add some explanation of your code, specifically what it does, and how it will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
public FaceDetection() {
    initComponents();
    //Adding Frame Icon
    try {
        this.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("WASP.png")));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FaceDetection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}'
```

this works for me.