# Setting JFrame icon - can't get suggested solutions in previous threads working

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am trying to set a `JFrame` icon. I have tried all the suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657569/how-to-set-icon-to-jframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614772/how-to-change-jframe-icon) , but have not yet had success.

In my method below you can see all the solutions attempted:

1 and 2 do not set an icon (I still see the coffee cup).

3 and 6 get this error:

```
The method setIconImage(Image) is undefined for the type Icon
```

4 gets this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

5 get:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from URL to DocFlavor.URL
```

My calling class is here:

```
/Users/lawrence/eclipse-workspace/COA_Application/src/main/java/misc/Icon
```

My image is here:

```
/Users/lawrence/eclipse-workspace/COA_Application/Logo.png
```

(I have also tried `COA_Application/src/main/resources/Logo.png`)

I am a beginner so apologies if I am being slow. Note also I am using a mac.

```
package misc;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Color;

public class Icon {
    
    static String filepath = "/Logo.png";
    
    public void showFrame() throws IOException {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Icon frame");
        
        //method 4
    frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource(filepath)));
        
         //method 1
        //BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));
        //frame.setIconImage(myPicture);
        
        //method 2
        //frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File(filepath)));
        
        //method 3
        //setIconImage(new ImageIcon(filepath).getImage());
        
        //method 5
        //URL url = getClass().getResource(filepath);
        //frame.setIconImage(imgicon.getImage());
        
        //method 6
        //ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./icon.png"));
        //setIconImage(img.getImage());
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Icon obj = new Icon();
        obj.showFrame();
    }
}
```

Image:
[image: My icon]

Comment: The folder holding the image has to be on the classpath for some of these methods to work.

Comment: Step 1 should work. ImageIO will generate an I/O Exception message if the image can't be found. Also, make sure the image is a proper size. I think it should be 16x16 or maybe 32x32. See if the image can be displayed as an Icon on a JLabel. If it displays on the label but not the frame icon then the size is probably the issue.

Comment: Gilbert - the image is in my application/target/classes, which I understand to be the classpath, but the methods don't work. Camickr - I have resized the image to 16x16 pixels (also smaller), but still not working. It does display on a JLabel

Comment: If you're aware of `getClass().getResource(filepath)` you must have also stumbled across the fact that an embedded resource (not available as a `File`) need to be referenced from either the root of the class-path or a location relative to the package of the calling class. We don't know that the directory / package structure of the locations of the image **or** the class, so I don't see how you think we can help.

Comment: My calling class is here: /Users/lawrence/eclipse-workspace/COA_Application/src/main/java/misc/Icon . My image is here: /Users/lawrence/eclipse-workspace/COA_Application/Logo.png (I have also tried COA_Application/src/main/resources/Logo.png  . Does that answer your question?

Comment: *"Does that answer your question?"* [edit] the information into the question. I'm not clear what the root of the class-path is. Providing the `package ..` line of the class should help clarify that (the first part of the `..` should be in the root of the class-path. To have `getResource` presume the path should be found from the root of the class-path, prefix it with `/`. I find it a lot more reliable to go from the root, than use a path relative to the class.

Comment: I have tried "../Logo.png" and still no icon. Note: In order to get past the 'static reference' error blocking the getResource method, I have moved everything into the main method, created an object of the class ('obj') and changed the line to frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(obj.getClass().getResource(filepath))); Hope this is correct

Comment: I went through the question and edited to use code formatting on both the paths and compilation errors. Only now do I realise how much you've been trying anything you see / can think of, yet not understanding the problem or knowing how to fix it. Part of the problems described are because of `static` declarations. That stuffs up trying to get access to resources, as well as other things. It's the first thing that should be fixed, by removing the `static` keyword and creating an instance of the class to use for calling the `showFrame` method, then within the method..

Comment: .. we can use something like `this.getClass()..` without compilation problems (and in a form where it might work, subject to the correct path). But here is where I get stuck, you did not provide the `package` statement so I am still not sure where the root of the class-path is. I *suspect* the the image is located outside the class-path, never built into the Jar, and therefore unavailable via `getResource`..

Comment: Thanks for your patience; clearly I need to do some homework! The package statement is: package miscPackage; . The first part of the output of System.out.println(System.getProperty ("java.class.path")); is /Users/lawrence/eclipse-workspace/COA_Application/target/classes , my png file is in there

Comment: *"The package statement is: package miscPackage;"* Wait .. *what?*  I expected the package to be (assuming the class name is `Icon`) something like `package misc;` or `package main.java.misc;`. Please post a [mre] of code. It should include the `package` statement and class name.

Comment: Sorry for confusion - I'd renamed the package in an attempt to fix. I've changed it back to 'misc' now and updated the code above

Comment: Apologies, I'll be more accurate in future. I'm aware of the time I am taking you, and don't want to ask too much, so perhaps we should leave this unresolved. The first fix did not work. I have not packaged anything in jars as yet, I am running my application from eclipse

Comment: *"I am running my application from eclipse"* Are you certain that Eclipse is not making a Jar? Then check the place (directory) it puts 'classes and resources'. I suggested that because IDE's will only include resources (copy them) onto the run-time class-path if they are in particular starting directories. `resources` is a typical directory name for such to happen, but I'm not positive Eclipse uses it.

Comment: It could well be making a jar, not sure where I would find that however. I'm using Maven so I think the paths are src/main/java for classes and src/main/resources for resources. My icon file is in the latter

Comment: *"I think the paths are src/main/java"* An IDE typically has source code in one path, but classes in another. Use the desktop file manager to go in there and have a look around.

Comment: I can see a 'classes' folder in eclipse-workspace > COA_Application (my project) > target > classes. Could that be it? My png is already in there, however. There is no 'resources' folder there, or anywhere else in my project other than 'src'.

Comment: Huh.. so is the image in the root of `classes`?

Comment: Yes. It's in 3 places actually - (1) COA_Application, (2) COA_Application > target > classes, (3) COA_Application > src > main > resources.

Comment: O...K so have you tried `"/Logo.png"`?

Comment: Yes - when I use "Logo.png" I get a null pointer exception, when I use "/Logo.png" the program launches but with a coffee cup icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Of course, the devil is in the details. The (upper / lower) case used for the path and resource name must be exactly as they are on the file system. The easiest way to make `getResource(..)` to works is to use a path from the root of the class-path. Specifying 'from the root' is done by prefixing the path with `/`.

Example using latest code (loads the icon from URL):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Icon {
    
    public void showFrame() throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Icon frame");
        
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ8fP.png");
        frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url));
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Icon obj = new Icon();
        obj.showFrame();
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Given it works perfectly here, I'm starting to think the problem is the particular JRE being used.

> I have just built and installed my application and it has the correct icon!

Comment: Andrew - no sorry, not sorted yet. There's no null pointer exception, but I still have the default icon (not the one I'm trying to set). The embedded resource solution seems to refer to method 5 above, for which I get this error: 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from URL to DocFlavor.URL'

Comment: Ugh.. that seems obvious when I read what I quoted, again. My bad. OK .. can you create a new MRE, and upload this image to the question? I've not before seen a problem with loading a PNG image in Java (once there is a valid URL to it), but there is always a first time.

Comment: No worries. I think you're saying to update my MRE above and attach my icon, which I've now done. Let me know if you meant to create a fresh post or something else

Comment: Report back the result you get when running the code after *"Example using latest code (loads the icon from URL):"* at the end of my answer..

Comment: Seriously? Given it works perfectly here, I'm starting to think the problem is the particular JRE being used.

Comment: You were right - I have just built and installed my application and it has the correct icon! Not a problem that it doesn't show in Eclipse. Thanks for all your help Andrew, really appreciate it

Comment: *"I have just built and installed my application and it has the correct icon!"* Congrats! I've edited the solution into my answer (just quoting your comment). *"Thanks for all your help Andrew"* A great way to show gratitude, as well as make the question & answer more prominent to others searching later, is to accept the answer (as noted above in my first comment on the answer).