# applying color to specific dates in calendar

Tags: java, swing, calendar, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have developed a java code which displays calendar in swings... I want some specific dates to be in a different color...how to do that ..please do help me ...
I am using setvalueAt() function to insert dates in to the table...
I used some sort of "\033[31;1m%1$d\033[0m" to change color...but its not working...

```
package project1_swings;

     import javax.swing.*;
     import javax.swing.event.*;
     import javax.swing.table.*;
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;
     import java.util.*;
     import java.io.*;
     public class CalendarProgram{
     static JLabel lblMonth, lblYear;
     static JButton btnPrev, btnNext;
     static JTable tblCalendar;
     static JComboBox cmbYear;
     static JFrame frmMain;
     static Container pane;
     static DefaultTableModel mtblCalendar; 
     static JScrollPane stblCalendar; 
     static JPanel pnlCalendar;
     static int realYear, realMonth, realDay, currentYear, currentMonth;




    public static void main (String args[])
     {

        try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());}
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
        catch (InstantiationException e) {}
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {}


        frmMain = new JFrame ("Calendar of events"); 
        frmMain.setSize(330, 375); 
        pane = frmMain.getContentPane(); 
        pane.setLayout(null); 
        frmMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 


        lblMonth = new JLabel ("July");
        lblYear = new JLabel ("Year:    2014");
        cmbYear = new JComboBox();
        btnPrev = new JButton ("&lt;&lt;");
        btnNext = new JButton ("&gt;&gt;");
        mtblCalendar = new DefaultTableModel(){public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex,           int mColIndex){return false;}};
        tblCalendar = new JTable(mtblCalendar);
        stblCalendar = new JScrollPane(tblCalendar);
        pnlCalendar = new JPanel(null);

        pnlCalendar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Events shown in  brackets"));

        pane.add(pnlCalendar);
        pnlCalendar.add(lblMonth);
        pnlCalendar.add(lblYear);
        pnlCalendar.add(stblCalendar);


        pnlCalendar.setBounds(0, 0, 320, 335);
        lblMonth.setBounds(160-lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width/2, 25, 100, 25);
        lblYear.setBounds(10, 305, 80, 20);
        cmbYear.setBounds(230, 305, 80, 20);
        btnPrev.setBounds(10, 25, 50, 25);
        btnNext.setBounds(260, 25, 50, 25);
        stblCalendar.setBounds(10, 50, 300, 250);

        frmMain.setResizable(false);
        frmMain.setVisible(true);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); 
        realDay = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
        realMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH); 
        realYear = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR); 
        currentMonth = realMonth;
        currentYear = realYear;


        String[] headers = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"}; 
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++){
            mtblCalendar.addColumn(headers[i]);
        }

        tblCalendar.getParent().setBackground(tblCalendar.getBackground()); 

        tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

        tblCalendar.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblCalendar.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblCalendar.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        tblCalendar.setRowHeight(38);
        mtblCalendar.setColumnCount(7);
        mtblCalendar.setRowCount(6);

        for (int i=realYear-100; i<=realYear+100; i++){
            cmbYear.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        refreshCalendar (realMonth, realYear); 
    }

    public static void refreshCalendar(int month, int year){

        try
        {
        String[] months =  {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        int nod, som; //Number Of Days, Start Of Month

        //Allow/disallow buttons
        btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
        btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        month=6;
        year=2014;
        //if (month == 0 && year <= realYear-10){btnPrev.setEnabled(false);} //Too early
        //if (month == 11 && year >= realYear+100){btnNext.setEnabled(false);} //Too late
        lblMonth.setText(months[month]); //Refresh the month label (at the top)
       // lblMonth.setBounds(160-lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width/2, 25, 180, 25); //Re-align label with calendar
        //cmbYear.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(year)); //Select the correct year in the combo box

        //Clear table
       // for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
         //   for (int j=0; j<7; j++){
           //     mtblCalendar.setValueAt(null, i, j);
            //}
        //}

        //Get first day of month and number of days
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        nod = cal.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        som = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String fname,line;

        //Draw calendar
        for (int i=1; i<=nod; i++){
            try
            {
                  fname="F:/Task Manager/"+i+".txt";
                  File fn=new File(fname);
                  if(!fn.exists())
                    {
                       int row = new Integer((i+som-2)/7);
                       int column  =  (i+som-2)%7;
                       mtblCalendar.setValueAt(i, row, column);
                    }
                  else
                  {
                      try
                      {
                      int count=0;
                     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
                     while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                     {
                        count++; 
                     }

                     int row = new Integer((i+som-2)/7);
                     int column  =  (i+som-2)%7;

                     mtblCalendar.setValueAt(i+"("+count+")", row, column);

                      }
                      catch(NumberFormatException m)
                      {
                          System.err.println(m);
                      }
                  }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        //Apply renderers
        tblCalendar.setDefaultRenderer(tblCalendar.getColumnClass(0), new tblCalendarRenderer());
        }
        catch(Exception n)
        {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }

    static class tblCalendarRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column){
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);
            if (column == 0 || column == 6){ //Week-end
                setBackground(new Color(255, 220, 220));
            }
            else{ //Week
                setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            }
            if (value != null){
                if (Integer.parseInt(value.toString()) == realDay && currentMonth == realMonth && currentYear == realYear){ //Today
                    setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 255));
                }
            }
            setBorder(null);
            setForeground(Color.black);
            return this;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: What does it means `I used some sort of "\033[31;1m%1$d\033[0m" to change color`? Which color you tried to change?

Comment: means "\033[31;1mHELLO\033[0m" which print HELLO in red color ...in the same way I tried printing the date in red color...

Comment: And where is HELLO in your code?

Comment: @AnilB I executed your code and it is displaying sun/sat column in light red color and today's date in light blue color. isn't you trying to achieve the same?

Comment: nope..I am working on a TODO list ..I want to make the dates which contain events in a different color than those without events... I am working on a TaskManager project

Answer (score 0):

**Your code**

```
 if (column == 0 || column == 6){ //Week-end
                    setBackground(new Color(255, 220, 220));
                }
                else{ //Week
                    setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                }
```

**Instead use this.**

```
if(row == 0 && column == 6)
            setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
        else
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
```

[You should refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181699/changing-swing-jtable-cell-colors)