# How to make a row in JTable with 367 cells where only the first one has text and the rest have colors

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, tablecellrenderer

I am working on a color based database program that shows bookings inside an accommodation based on color. the problem I've been having is that the table has 367 columns (the name of the accommodation and then all days of a year.) the problem I've been having is that I can't figure out how to make the first column of the row display a string and the rest a color.

I made a basic renderer that should display colors but I don't know how to use it.

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean   isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
   {
       Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
       if (! table.isRowSelected(row))
       { 
           if(row == 2 && column == 2)
               c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
           else
               c.setBackground(table.getBackground());  
       } 
       return c;
   } 
}
```

how would I integrate this with a JTable?

PS I have a header I want to show but the rows should be empty to begin with. then when a button is pressed it should add a row. this last button I can make myself I just need help with the cellrenderer

At the moment my JTable is initialized like this: `JTable table = new JTable();`

Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: Place the information you want in the `TableModel`, provide a custom `TableCellRenderer` which takes the `value` and converts to the required color and sets the background

Comment: As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552644/how-do-i-color-individual-cells-of-a-jtable-based-on-the-value-in-the-cell/30553979#30553979) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082098/how-to-give-a-jtable-cell-different-background-colour/28082202#28082202)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there is two state for a day, booked or not. So the `value` is boolean. You can set renderers by class types. For example:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new MyRenderer());
```

With that, your renderer will be uses only if `value` is a boolean.

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean   isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
   {
       Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 

           if(value)
               c.setBackground(/*Color for booked days*/ );
           else
               c.setBackground(table.getBackground());  

       return c;
   } 
}
```

Comment: There are going to be a few colors depending on how many persons booked so i would just use an int instead?

Comment: You can use `enum` for different situations. `public enum RoomState {AVALIABLE, BOOKED, BOOKED2}`

Comment: And decide the color in cellrenderer depend on the state.

Comment: So i pass an enum value to the object that was the boolean before

Comment: Pass enum value to the table and handle it cell renderer.