# How to colorize rows of a JTable after searching?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working with Java Netbeans and I've a `JTable` which contains many values and I'm doing a search. This is my code - it works well.

```
private void txtRechEHSKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    String re=comboSearchByEHS.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sql = "select * from equipement where "+re+" like ? ";
    try{
         ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, txtRechEHS.getText()+"%");
       SearchEHS();
    }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    } 
}
```

I want that when it searches and gets the result, that the found row the user is looking for gets colorized.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why not implement a [`RowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) (which is also a **filter**)?  Nothing highlights the found record(s) as good as making them the only ones to appear!  See also this [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28621618/418556) that filters a font list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) for that purpose or (in some cases) [DefaultTableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html)

*upd

See [SO Changing Swing JTable Cell Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181699), [SO Change background color of one cell in JTable [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348932)